# Carousel not sliding automatically JQuery 1.12.4 and Bootstrap 3.3.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My carousel is not sliding properly and I have no idea why. It slides nicely while navigating indicators, but won't slide on its own.
Any ideas why?

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="app/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Carousel -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 3000,
      pause: false
    })
  });    
</script>
```

Carousel part

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide vertical nicer">


    <!-- Wrapper for Slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- Set the first background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('app/images/6.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 1</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <!-- Set the second background image using inline CSS below. -->
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('app/images/23.jpg');"></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>Caption 2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
      <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="nicer carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the data attribute to activate the carousel. Change your opening HTML tag to this:

From this:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide vertical nicer">
```

To this:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide vertical nicer" data-ride="carousel">
```

See more here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and it works fine, sliding on its own and everything

Comment: Is it possible, that it is my Mozilla on Ubuntu, that can't handle this?

Comment: Unlikely. Here is a JsFiddle with you exact code except I added images from placehold.it to show you the example - https://jsfiddle.net/michaelsherry/vbqhupqj/

Only other change was that I changed the pause option in your jquery

Comment: Do you have a link to the live site with the issue?

Comment: No, I'm running it in deveopment mode in my localhost. Can that be an issue?

Comment: Shouldn't be. Are you running on Wordpress by any chance?

Comment: Only other little thing that I saw was wrong in your code was the pause option in the Jquery. Try changing from false to null